# RViz: ros package using_markers not found

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin, roscpp, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I tried to follow tutorials for rviz in http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes

However, after I did it step by step, ros cannot find the package even though I have sourced setup.bash. Can someone help me out? Great thanks!!!

```
z1huo@z1huo-ThinkPad-P51:~$ catkin_create_pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs

usage: catkin_create_pkg [-h] [--meta] [-s [SYS_DEPS [SYS_DEPS ...]]]
                         [-b [BOOST_COMPS [BOOST_COMPS ...]]] [-V PKG_VERSION]
                         [-D DESCRIPTION] [-l LICENSE] [-a AUTHOR]
                         [-m MAINTAINER] [--rosdistro ROSDISTRO]
                         name [dependencies [dependencies ...]]
catkin_create_pkg: error: File exists: /home/z1huo/using_markers/CMakeLists.txt

z1huo@z1huo-ThinkPad-P51:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws

z1huo@z1huo-ThinkPad-P51:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make

Base path: /home/z1huo/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/z1huo/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/z1huo/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/z1huo/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/z1huo/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/z1huo/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/z1huo/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
[ 15%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[ 46%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 69%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_eus
[ 84%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[100%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_nodejs
[100%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages

z1huo@z1huo-ThinkPad-P51:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash

z1huo@z1huo-ThinkPad-P51:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun using_markers basic_shapes

[rospack] Error: package 'using_markers' not found
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293735/rviz:-ros-package-using_markers-not-found/) by [z1huo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35608/z1huo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that

```
z1huo@z1huo-ThinkPad-P51:~$ catkin_create_pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs
```

was executed from your home directory rather than in the [source space](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Source_Space) (`src` directory) of your workspace. Therefore, it can't be found by `catkin_make`. It's easy to miss (and misunderstand), but in the tutorial that you linked to it tells you (my emphasis added)

> Before getting started, let's create a package called `using_markers`, **somewhere in your package path**:
>
> ```
> catkin_create_pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs
> ```

This basically means to run that command from the `src` directory of a `catkin` workspace. Now, try the same command, but from your `src` directory just as follows

```
z1huo@z1huo-ThinkPad-P51:~/catkin_ws/src$ catkin_create_pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs
```

These are pretty basic concepts (that you need to put packages in the `src` directory and compile from the root of your workspace), so I suggest that you go through the [tutorials on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) until these concepts are really driven in.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-10**:
Make sure to use the advice that @gvdhoorn gave you in one of your previous questions (#q292904) which is basically what I've outlined here. (As a side note, you should also accept that answer as it tells you how to solve your issue.)